# nodejs unlink files fs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to delete array of files but one or two of them gets deleted .Pls check the code I am sure I am doing something wrong.
I am searching for a file in directory and if found I am First Removing it from db..and after response I am removing file from directory

```
if (files.length > 0) {
    files.forEach(function(filename) {
        fileDir = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads/' + decodeURI(filename));
        fs.stat(fileDir, function(err, stats) {
            if (stats.isFile()) {
                // fs.unlink(fileDir, function(err) {

                form_op.deleteImg(url.resolve('http://localhost/uploads/', filename), query._id, function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw console.log(err)
                    }
                    fs.unlink(fileDir);
                });
                // });
            }

        });
        done++;
    });
```

through debugging I found that filename and fileDir variable are getting next file in the array without waiting for  `fs.stat(fileDir, function(err, stats) {` to complete.. is there any other way I can do it? the check and remove??
my files variable is array only file's name.

Answer (score 2):

`fileDir = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads/' + decodeURI(filename));`

You are missing a `var` declaration here, therefore the fileDir variable is global and shared by all of your callbacks.

Use `var fileDir = ...` to have the variable scoped to your function.

Comment: np, it's a pretty common trap. [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) can be helpful to prevent it